# User meta query using Wildcard

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, user-meta

I have created a custom plugin which writes new user meta data.

Each user has an array PER post so the meta_keys look like:

custompostid eg: custom3456, custom4565, custom 3576 etc

Each key holds an array:

custom3456(
   custom1=>postid
   custom2=>We are open
   custom3=>5
   custom4=>250
   )

I am now trying to create a dashboard to output this info in one place.

**EDIT: Logic Walkthrough**

1. Get all user meta data:

```
    $user = get_current_user_id();
    $data = get_user_meta($user);
```

2. For each key in $data starting with "custom" - print values

I need help with number 2.

For clarity, for the current logged in user I am looking to output all of the meta values (in turn) for each meta key named "custom%".

Could I have some guideance please.

Comment: Have you tried `'meta_key' => 'custom%'`? The % should be the wildcard you're looking for.

Comment: `WP_User_Query` and `get_user_meta()` do not support wildcards based on the meta _key_. Only the value. You'll probably want to store your data differently. Can you describe what you're ultimately doing?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Sure, I am open to suggestions, especially if it makes my storage more efficient.  Every post on my website is a business.  If a business has a specific payment plan then logged in users can interact with my custom plugin.  These interactions are captured and stored as the values change during interaction.  As each user can interact with hundreds of businesses I chose to store my data against the user as an array within custom.postID meta key.  Now I need to output all of the custom.postID meta values from all custom.% keys for the logged in user.

Comment: Hm, honestly it sounds like a custom table would be the optimal way to go.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the outputs I need with the current structure?

Comment: I'd avoid storing serialised data in keys, use separate keys for sub-fields ( there are security implications to serialising and deserialising, it opens you up to object deserialisation attacks )

Comment: @TomJNowell - Here is how I current update the user meta. How would I change this to your suggestion?   $the_meta_array = array (
     'custom1' => $user_custom1,
     'custom2' => $user_custom2,
  );  
  $user_meta_key = 'custom' . $pid;  
  update_user_meta( $uid, $user_meta_key, $the_meta_array );

Comment: Either JSON encode/decode, or use multiple user meta fields, or multiple fields with the same name

Comment: @TomJNowell I have been mulling this over and have no clear direction.  I want to structure my data in the most efficient way in the db and am willing to make the changes now rather than further down the line.  Every logged in user needs to have data stored for every post.  Currently when they use my plugin, the API validates the interaction and creates one key in user_meta (custom-postID) with 6 subkeys each with a value.  This is stored serialised and is a pain to extract, sum etc. Can I ask your preferred method please? Would you even store against the user or perhaps the post?